# Производительность NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft

### Предыстория

Я работаю с протоколом `Minecraft`. И когда возник вопрос о производительности, я достаточно обиделся, потому, что скорость загрузки чанков была очень низкая, я перебирал территорию размером `16777216` блоков, тоесть **256x256x256**, и просто устанавливал случайных блок, и это происходило довольно медленно, на создание полностью заполненного случайными блоками чанка, уходило около 3 - 4 секунд. В то время, как скорость загрузки чанков в одиночной игре достигало на глаз около 8 - 10 чанков в секунду, а там используются довольно сложные алгоритмы генерации мира.

### Текущая реализация

На данный момент у меня есть пара функций, кодирующая и декодирующая пакет протокола.
Выглядит это так

```
class XPacket extends Packet {
  encode(){ /**/ }
  decode(){ /**/ }
}
```

Эти методы выполняют в себе цепочку вызовов методов `Packet`, таким образом кодируя и декодируя данные из/в поля(ей) `XPacket`.

`Packet` внутри себя использует специальный буфер, по сути это обычный `Buffer`, просто расширенный специальными методами:

```
writeByte(...value: number[]): this { /**/ } 
writeUByte(...value: number[]): this { /**/ }
writeInt(...value: number[]): this { /**/ }
writeUInt(...value: number[]): this { /**/ }
```

Так же он содержит более сложные методы и аналогичные им для чтения, все они **переопределяют** буфер с новым значением.

Вот к примеру один из методов:

```
writeVarint(value: varint): this {
  this.buffer = Buffer.concat([data, new Varint().write(value)])
  return this
}
```

**Varint.ts**

```
export class Varint extends DataType<number> {

  private readonly SEGMENT_BITS = 0x7f
  private readonly CONTINUE_BIT = 0x80
  protected readonly maxLength: number = 32

  read(data: Buffer): [result: number, offset: number] {
    let result = 0
    let offset = 0
    let position = 0
    let currentByte: number

    while (true) {
      currentByte = data.readInt8(offset)
      offset++
      result |= (currentByte & this.SEGMENT_BITS) << position
      if ((currentByte & this.CONTINUE_BIT) === 0) break
      position += 7
      if (position >= this.maxLength)
        throw new Error('Varint is too big')
    }

    return [result, offset]
  }

  write(value: number): Buffer {
    let buf = Buffer.alloc(0)
    while (true) {
      if ((value & ~this.SEGMENT_BITS) == 0) {
        buf = Buffer.concat([buf, Buffer.from([value])])
        break
      }
      buf = Buffer.concat([
        buf,
        Buffer.from([(value & this.SEGMENT_BITS) | this.CONTINUE_BIT])
      ])
      value >>>= 7
    }
    return buf
  }

}
```

И также один из пакетов к примеру:

```
export class PlayerPositionAndLookClientPacket extends Packet {

  static type: number = 0x38
  static state: number = PacketState.Play

  // Не обращайте внимания на типы double и т.д. это просто алиасы к              
  // типам number и bigint

  x: double = 0
  y: double = 0
  z: double = 0
  yaw: float = 0
  pitch: float = 0
  flags: byte = 0
  teleportId: varint = 0
  dismount: boolean = false

  constructor() {
    super(PlayerPositionAndLookClientPacket.state, PlayerPositionAndLookClientPacket.type)
  }

  encode(): void {
    this
      .writeDouble(this.x, this.y, this.z)
      .writeFloat(this.yaw, this.pitch)
      .writeByte(this.flags)
      .writeVarint(this.teleportId)
      .writeBoolean(this.dismount)
  }

  decode(): void {
    this.x = this.readDouble()
    this.y = this.readDouble()
    this.z = this.readDouble()
    this.yaw = this.readFloat()
    this.pitch = this.readFloat()
    this.flags = this.readByte()
    this.teleportId = this.readVarint()
    this.dismount = this.readBoolean()
  }

}
```

Далее я просто склеиваю методом длину пакета с его данными и отправляю клиенту через встроенный пакет `net`

```
get data(): Buffer {
  return Buffer.concat([
    new Varint().write(this.buffer.length + 1),
    new Varint().write(this.type),
    this.buffer,
  ])
}
```

### C++ ?

Может быть перенести этот **специальный** буфер в аддон `c++`? Но тут есть проблема, я не знаю как, т.к. почти не знаю `c++`. Но это меньшая из проблем на данный момент.

### GPU.js

Нашёл я библиотечку [GPU.js](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js/), вроде бы как она умеет делать вычисления на **GPU**. Есть ли в ней смысл. Также она вряд ли запустится на **Linux** сервере.

### NodeJS не для этих целей

Возможно `NodeJS` для того, что я пытаюсь сделать и вовсе не подходит?

**Вообщем я хочу получить ответ, о том, может ли `NodeJS` выполнять описанное выше быстрее, если да то как?**

Comment: У вас максимально абстрактное описание так что сказать что именно тормозит довольно трудно. В общем случае надо профилировать, смотреть где тормозит и чинить.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да спасибо, я добавил несколько примеров из моей реализации

Comment: Ну, надо профилировать. Так сходу меня смущает огромное количество создания буферов.

Comment: Попробуйте расставить таймстампы и найти какая именно чать кода работает медленно. Будет проще разбираться в причине

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev Я провёл тест, в котором выполнил **100 000** конкатенаций с буфером и получил результат в **1.9s**, во втором тесте, я выполнил `Buffer.alloc(/* некоторое большое число */)` и выполнял `writeUint8`, и результат намного лучше: `8ms`. Минус этого решения очевиден, выделять мегабайты буферу, в котором будет непредсказуемое количество байт - неправильно.